# Pulley on an Inclined Plane

Tags: classical-mechanics

Two particles P and Q are attached to opposite ends of a light inextensible string which passes over a small
smooth pulley at the top of a rough plane inclined at 30° to the horizontal. P has mass 0.2 kg and is held at
rest on the plane. Q has mass 0.2 kg and hangs freely. The string is taut (see diagram). The coefficient of
friction between P and the plane is 0.4. The particle P is released.
Q strikes the floor and remains at rest. P continues to move up the plane for a further distance of 0.8 m
before it comes to rest. P does not reach the pulley.
Find the speed of the particles immediately before Q strikes the floor.

For this question I need to set 0.2a =  0.2gsin30 + 0.4x0.2gcos30. I don't really understand why we need to do this. Why couldn't I just use these simultaneous equations 0.2g - T = 0.2a and 0.2a = T- 0.2gsin30 -0.4x0.2gcos30? (The mark scheme says that this problem cannot be solved using these equations, but I don't understand why).

If you could provide any advice, I would really appreciate it.[image]

Comment: More appropriate for physics SE IMO

Comment: I don't know what you mean by SE IMO. Could you please explain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint.

The friction work after the hanging ball strikes the floor is

$$
\mathcal{T}_f = \mu m_P g \cos\theta\Delta l 
$$

so we have

$$
\frac 12 m_P v_P^2 = \mathcal{T}_f + m_P g \Delta l \sin\theta
$$

Here

$$
\cases{
\mu  =  0.4\\
m_P = 0.2\\
\Delta l = 0.8\\
g = 9.81\\
\theta = 30^{\circ}
}
$$